# Datatable does not update after successful ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a data table. Each row of the table has a `commandButton` called *'Remove'*, which is supposed to remove that row from the model and the view and perform an update in-place. As a footer, I have another `commandButton` called *'Remove every row'*.

The last button works. I click on it, every row is removed from the model (i.e the `ArrayList` containing the elements becomes empty) and the `dataTable` and `footer facet` is re-rendered (or updated) in the view.

On the other hand, when I click a button on one of the rows, to remove it, it partially works. The corresponding element is removed from the model but the view is not updated. That row is still there in the `dataTable` and the `footer facet` hasn't changed.

I have the following piece of code in my `users.xhtml`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{users.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{users.init}" />
</f:metadata>

...

<h:form id="usersForm">
    <p:outputPanel>    
        <p:dataTable id="userTable" value="#{users.user.friendList}" var="friend">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{friend.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton action="#{users.user.removeFriend(friend)}"
                    ajax="true"
                    update="userTable somethingElse" process="@this"
                    onerror="errorDialog.show();"
                    icon="ui-icon-delete"
                    title="delete user">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

            <f:facet id="somethingElse" name="footer">  
                    aye: ${users.user.xxx}
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>

    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:commandButton action="#{users.user.removeAllFriends()}" ajax="true"
                update="userTable somethingElse"
                process="@this"
                icon="ui-icon-close"
                value="delete all friends?">
    </p:commandButton>


</h:form>
```

So, what do you think is the problem here?

I'm using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.0

Comment: Do not ask multiple questions in a single question. One question per question, please :) I have edited the other question out. Also the linked previous question is not related at all. It's maybe the same code, but the problem is absolutely not the same. As to your current problem: which PF version are you using? What if you use `update="@form"` instead?

Comment: Sorry for the bad words but thank you very much, once again :) About multiple questions, I'll try to do my best the next time :)

Comment: I reposted it as an answer :)

Comment: @BalusC - I reposted my second question as a seperate question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804020/handling-erroneous-ajax-calls-with-primefaces-3-0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recognize this problem form one of our current PF 3.0 pages. It will work if you use `update="@form"` instead. I haven't really had the time to investigate the real cause so that I can report it to the PF guys, because this problem does not manifest in all pages. Even in the same table, a different button works as intented.

Give it a try:

```
<p:commandButton update="@form" ... />
```

---

**Update**: coming to think about it, it's maybe related to the presence of `process="@this"`.

Comment: I like your answer better because it is much more efficient and clean.  I wonder if this fix will work for apps running on Primefaces 2.2.1 as well?  I will have to test this and find out when I have more time.

Comment: I have an existing project in PF 3.2 and this is still an issue. Does anyone know if it has been fixed in a later version?

Comment: @Catfish: this has been acknowledged and fixed in PF 3.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516397/how-to-ajax-update-the-pdatatable-from-inside-the-pdatatable-itself/12517181#12517181

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Primefaces 2.2.1 as this seems like it is due to a common bug with the Primefaces dataTable component.  Essentially what occurs is that ajax postbacks occurring from within elements of a dataTable will not result in a partial page update of elements in the dataTable.

The simplest workaround is to invoke a postback from a button outside of the dataTable where its sole purpose is simply to partial page update the dataTable.  This is not the most efficient solution as it results in two postbacks, however it does work.

See my previous answer to this problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422151/primefaces-inline-datatable-delete-functionality/6424863#6424863)

Comment: I'm actually using Primefaces 3.0. Does it also have this bug?

Comment: It was my impression that this was fixed in 3.0 however I haven't been using 3.0 that long to have run into this yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use server IDs for updating components (like `userTable`, `somethingElse`, ...), these components need to be in the same naming container as the component which triggers the update (your button for example). Otherwise you need to use an expression like this within the update attribute: `update=":usersForm:userTable"`.

The main problem is to identify the naming containers. The outer button does work, because it is in the same naming container (the form) as the table with the ID `userTable`. The facet gets updated because the whole table gets updated, but since datatable is a naming container itself, it should **not** be possible to update the footer by just using `update="somethingElse"` on the outer button.

I'm not sure, why the inner button does not work. I guess there is another naming container within the datatable. PrimeFaces does log an INFO, if the component could not be found using the [findComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) algorithm of the [UIComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) implementation. `INFO: Cannot find component with identifier "userTable" in view.`

Answer (score 1):

I had filters in my datatable. So here I resolved the problem with

```
oncomplete="PF('myWidgetVar').filter()" and update="@form"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using `update="@form"` and it didn't completely work: it wasn't updating the number of rows in the dataTable, for instance. What I already had in place was this on the button that updated the form:

`process="@this" oncomplete="updateRC();"`

and then just below I had:

`<p:remoteCommand name="updateRC" process="@this" update="@form" />`

---

What I did to fix the rows update problem is add a styleClass to the dataTable, e.g. "myTable", and then add a jQuery selector to that class in the above remoteCommand, e.g.:

`<p:remoteCommand name="updateRC" process="@this" update="@form @(.myTable)" />`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to refresh  in jsf 2.0

```
<p:dataTable  id="empl1" var="emp" value="#{dtEmployeeView.employee}" selectionMode="multiple"  rowKey="#{emp.id}"
                              paginator="true" rows="5" tableStyleClass="ui-table-columntoggle">
    <p:column width="20" headerText="Id"  priority="1">
        <h:link value="#{emp.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Employee Name" priority="2">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.pname}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton update="form1:empl1" ajax="true" value="Submit" action="#{empService.addEmployee(employee)}" >
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{dtEmployeeView.init()}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```