# JSF2.0 - Handling erroneous Ajax calls with Primefaces 3.0

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a `commandButton` in my .xhtml page:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{someone.doSomething()}"
                ajax="true"
                onerror="errorDialog.show();">
</p:commandButton>
```

It's simply making an Ajax call. How can I detect situations such as internet connection problem (of the client/browser), timeout, session-timeout, server-side exceptions, crashes etc in the middle of an Ajax call so as to show an informative message to the user?

Does the `onerror` attribute of `p:ajax` handle all of those? If not, then what? :)
What's the default timeout btw?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onerror calls this function:
onerror(xhr, status, exception) - Javascript callback to process when ajax request fails. Takes three arguments, xmlhttprequest, status string and exception thrown if any.

This info is from documentation. xhr - is actually a request. So there can be found request status and a lot of other info.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{someone.doSomething()}"
            ajax="true"
            onerror="console.debug(xhr)">
</p:commandButton>
```

Try this code in chrome or firebug. It will show xhr object

Get a look into http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_0.pdf section 7.2 Ajax API

Comment: Thanks StrekoZ for the answer. But I was actually looking for a more in-depth answer. That'll have to do I guess.