# onerror on the <p:commandButton not working

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have primefaces command button as below:

```
 <p:commandButton id="btnContinue"
 value="Continue"
 style="float:right;"
 oncomplete="handleDialogSubmit(xhr, status, args);"
 update="form1, :view1:linksForm2:queryParameters"
 actionListener="#{controller.save}"
 onerror="handleError(xhr, status, args);"
 styleClass="continue-button" />
 ....
 ....

 <script type="text/javascript">
         function handleError(xhr, status, args) {
             alert("I a m here ...");
             alert("xhr : " + xhr);
             alert("status : " + status);
             alert("args : " + args);
         }
    </script>
```

When the error/exception occurs handleError() does not get called. But if I remove 'xhr, status, args' like below:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnContinue"
     value="Continue"
     style="float:right;"
     oncomplete="handleDialogSubmit(xhr, status, args);"
     update="form1, :view1:linksForm2:queryParameters"
     actionListener="#{controller.save}"
     onerror="handleError();"
     styleClass="continue-button" />
 ....
 ....

 <script type="text/javascript">
         function handleError() {
             alert("I a m here ...");
             alert("xhr : " + xhr);
             alert("status : " + status);
             alert("args : " + args);
         }
    </script>
```

Then I see alert 'I am here' and not the rest of them. 
How can I get access to xhr, status, args in the event of an error/exception ?

Thanks

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8819276/1692632

Comment: Inspect the error with firebug, it will probably show the error in function handleError(), because you are using variables that is not declared in the scope: xhr,status,args. Btw, why don't you pass those parameters to handleError too? like onerror="handleError(xhr,status,args);"

Comment: @ Darka : I tried that. It shows me the object in the console that has the status of 500 and executes the function 'handleDialogSubmit(xhr, status, args);'. What I am looking for is a global ajax error handling mechanism.

Comment: @Pellizon : I did try that 'handleError(xhr,status,args);' in the first code sample. That did not work though.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Where these 3 variables is coming from?