# General handling of AJAX call error on client side

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, error-handling

We have a JSF 2.2 application using PrimeFaces.

Now, when an error occurs, I check for an AJAX request and deliver a partial response (as shown in [BalusC's anwer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366936/jsf-filter-not-redirecting-after-initial-redirect)).

But what is, if there's no server anymore to handle the error, e.g. due to connection loss? At the moment, just nothing happens, leaving the user puzzled.

I found a hint in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804020/jsf2-0-handling-erroneous-ajax-calls-with-primefaces-3-0), which works, but I'd like to solve this in a general way, so that all AJAX calls which fail try to redirect to the start page - and then may receive the browser connection error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For standard JSF ajax, use [`jsf.ajax.addOnError()`](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.addOnError) to set the default error handler. E.g.

```js
jsf.ajax.addOnError(function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
});
```

See also chapter 13.3.6.2 of the [JSF 2.2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_2-fr-eval-spec/index.html). You can find all properties of `data` object in table 14-4 of the JSF spec.

For PrimeFaces 4+, hook `pfAjaxError` event in jQuery (before 4, just use `ajaxError`). E.g.

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxError", function(event, xhr, options) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Just customize it accordingly to show some div in top.