# How to only update JSF/Primefaces component value upon Ajax sucess, but do nothing on Ajax failure

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a JSF front end using Primefaces 5.3 which updates fields dynamically using Ajax.  The problem that I am having is that sometimes my Ajax calls fail (ex: server responds with a 500), but my front end is still changing.  Essentially, I'm looking to prevent the change of the input field if my ajax fails.  Stated differently, I only want the input field to change upon a successful Ajax response.

I'm fairly new to JSF, so I'm not sure how to handle this.  In regular HTML/JS, I would have been able to store the value onclick and in my ajax error handler restored the value, but I don't know how to do this using the PF framework.

```
        <div class="Container25">
            <p:selectOneRadio id="grid" value="#{cc.attrs.answer.singleAnswer.codeValue}" layout="grid" columns="1" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.menuItems}" 
                               var="item" itemLabel="#{msg[item.code]}" itemValue="#{item.code}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>

                 <p:ajax  event="change"  listener="#{cc.attrs.onChange}" update="#{cc.attrs.update}" disabled="#{cc.attrs.onChange == null }" global="false" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </div>
```

I've tried adding the resetValues attribute to the ajax component, but that hasn't helped.  Additionally, I've tried adding some custom JS in my `onstart` handler, but it is undefined.

I figured there must be a simple JSF/PF way of doing this, but can't seem to find it.

How can I either prevent the input value to change until the Ajax call returns successfully (ie: only change the value in the onsuccess handler) or reset my original radio button selection in the event that my Ajax call fails?  What do I need to put in my `onerror` handler to restore the pre-ajax state?

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538133/general-handling-of-ajax-call-error-on-client-side

Comment: I'd start with preventing the 500 errors or report in an error page what happend. Just reverting the values and staying on the same page is kind pf useless since putting in the same values would fail again.

Comment: @kukeltje. Agreed, but that isn't the question at the moment.  I do need to handle that situation, but I also need the ensure the front end is in a known or stable state.  Essentially the value change is dependent on a successful Ajax call.  So if the Ajax does not return a 200, I do not want my value to change.

Comment: I'd look at either using a passthrough attribute to store the original value and swapping them back onerror, with the understanding that you'll have to iterate over the radio elements with the same name and set the checked attribute. Or manually make a synchronous ajax call in the onclick event, returning false if it failed. You can check the rendered source to see the primefaces JS function for ajax. Keep in mind that this could bite you in a future release...

Comment: If you are SURE the values are not changed in the model, why not just fully reload the page in a non-ajax way (a get request, it will reload everything), or use the [PrimeFaces 'resetInput'](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml) functionality... (e.g. in combination with what is in the answer below, since this IS needed then) And if you know the next request will succeed, why not just have the user submit the same again of if you do not know that, why not prevent the user from entering wrong values...

Comment: But for me it is still weird that if an ajax call failed, you want to reset the form and then most likely the user will start entering the same values again... And I think it is 'weird' to that, as you state, "that is not the question now", about solving the 500 error.  It feels like a weird workaround (wrong hack would be a better phrasing in my opinion). But that is up to you... Hope you find a solution...

Comment: @Kukeltje I can't reload the page as there are many fields on the page that may not have been submitted and reloading would lose the data.  And I can't save b/c due to the way the page is structured, the failed ajax is causing an invalid state (ie: the form is missing fields that the server is expecting to receive on submit).  At the root, the form is badly designed, but I don't have the option to redesign the form at the moment; I need to find a workaround to handle the current system, and then take the time to redesign it correctly.

Comment: @Kukeltje is right. Try to convert exceptions into messages. You might want to add http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler for any (third party?) exceptions you might have left uncaught.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Primefaces RemoteCommand component for an easy solution, just embed it in your form:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="revertSomeValues"
            actionListener="#{relatedBean.revertValuesToDefaults}"
            update="componentId" />
```

And at the bean side you can manipulate the model:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class relatedBean implements Serializable {

  Integer  codeValue;
  //other model attributes and methods...

  public void revertValuesToDefaults() {        
     setCodeValue(0); //supposing 0 is the default value
    //handle other model attributes if needed
  }
}
```

Now you can set the onerror callback alike -> onerror="revertSomeValues()"

You can also update the components wtih Primefaces RequestContext programatically from your bean if needed:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.update("componentId");
```

Comment: When do you call this? The ajaxesults in a 500 error? Better to prevent that error

Comment: True but I considered it as a temporary server failure (maybe overloaded with requests which it couldn't distribute at that particular request's scope etc.) otherwise the whole question becomes irrelevant since the server goes down constantly, doesn't it?

Comment: The question or trick now is how to know what the preceding value was.  Assume I don't want the default value, but just the value the input was at prior to the Ajax error.  Is there a way to save that value in order to restore it?

Comment: In that case using a remote command would probably fail to... and yes, the question is in my opinion irrelevant/wrong approach. See my comment on the question

Comment: yes, probably. but there is no other option but to make yet another ajax request to try to handle the situation. whether with remotecommand (that I suggested for the easy use) or not. if the server is %100 dead of course none will work. and seems like the OP is asking a different thing.

Comment: @AlpA I have updated the question to clarify the need a little bit more.  In fact, I'm actually looking to only change the input value upon an Ajax success (200) return.  In the case of anything else, I want the original value to remain (not update).  But I am not sure how to accomplish that easily.

Comment: @Kukeltje Indeed; this is a bit of a hack to bandaid a problem in the application.  At the base of it, I am looking to prevent the input from changing unless the Ajax call is successful.  So basically only changing the input value in the onsuccess() handler.  Given that I couldn't find how to do that, I figure that reverting in the onerror() would be as effective.  If it is easier to only update the value onSuccess(), I'd be just as happy with that solution.