# p:dataTable row selection is not working(with a radio button column)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i implemented selectableDataModel and extend ListDataModel
i can excellently see the content of table.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="selectProductTable" var="product"  value="#{manageFormsView.productModel}" selection="#{manageFormsView.product}" >
    <p:column selectionMode="single"/>

<p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Urun Ismi" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{product.name}" />
                            </p:column> 


            </p:dataTable>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:commandButton action="#{manageFormsView.setSelectedProductToForm}"
                    update="main_form"
                    oncomplete="if(#{manageFormsView.errorText == 'SUCCESS'}){ selectProductDlg.hide();}"
                    value="sec">
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton onclick="selectProductDlg.hide();" action="#{manageFormsView.cancelSetRequest}"
                    value="Iptal">
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid> 


     </h:form>
```

but when i click 'sec' in `setSelectedProductToForm` function i expect to see `manageFormsView.product` with a content but it is null.

what may the problem be?

thanks

Comment: have you noticed that the update of "sec" is set to update="main_form"
while your form does not have an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you didn't implement `SelectableDataModel#getRowData()` and/or `getRowKey()` properly. The most basic implementation would look like this, assuming that you have a `Long id` representing a PK in your `Product` class:

```
@Override
public Object getRowKey(Product product) {
    return product.getId();
}

@Override
public Product getRowData(String rowKey) {
    Long id = Long.valueOf(rowKey);

    for (Product product : (List<Product>) getWrappedData()) {
        if (product.getId().equals(id)) {
            return product;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The `getRowKey()` is to be used to return the row identifier of the selectable rows. The `getRowData()` is to be used to return the whole object which is associated with the row identifier.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please note that the EL as you have there in `oncomplete` attribute is resolved on a per-view basis, not on a per-request basis. You might want to fix that as well. See also for example [EL expression inside p:commandButton onclick does not update/re-render on ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822484/el-expression-inside-pcommandbutton-onclick-does-not-update-re-render-on-ajax-r)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     <h:commandButton action="#{manageFormsView.setSelectedProductToForm}"
                oncomplete="if(#{manageFormsView.errorText == 'SUCCESS'}){ selectProductDlg.hide();}"
                value="sec">
               <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" />
     </h:commandButton>
```