# How to ajax-update the p:dataTable from inside the p:dataTable itself?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

```
<h:form id="formId">
   <p:wizard id="wizardId">
      <p:tab id="tabId">
         <p:dataTable id="tableId">
           <p:column>
             <h:commandLink value="remove" update=""/>
           </p:column>
         </p:dataTable>
      </p:tab>
   </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

I need to update only the `<p:dataTable>` without the entire form.
I tried using `@form`, `@parent`, `:formId:wizardId:tabId:tableId`, but none of them are working as I want. When I use `@form`, it is checking for validation which I don't need to do.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, this will indeed never work with a `<h:commandLink>`, simply because it doesn't support the `update` attribute at all. Perhaps you actually meant to use `<p:commandLink>`?

Once you've fixed the `<h:commandLink>` being a `<p:commandLink>`, then head to this answer: [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762) to learn how to reference components in JSF ajax.

After having read that answer, you should have found out that the datatable is in this particular code snippet identified by `:formId:tableId`. So, all with all, the following should do:

```
<p:commandLink value="remove" update=":formId:tableId" />
```

Note that there's until with PrimeFaces 3.3 a bug in ajax-updating of the `<p:dataTable>` in certain complex UI compositions. This is [fixed](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2119) in PrimeFaces 3.4. If you encounter exactly this problem and can't upgrade to PrimeFaces  3.4, then you'd need to wrap the table in some `<h:panelGroup id="tablePanelId">` and then use `update=":formId:tablePanelId"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Actually I was using `<p:commandLink>` I misspelled it as `<h:commandLink>` I got the solution by moving my datatable to `<h:panelGroup>`